# Answer is wrong when calculating future value in java

Tags: java

So I am creating a future value application, that allows the user to enter the amount they have invested, the percent per year, how many years it is invested, and if it is compounded annually, semi-annually, monthly, daily, etc.

The problem I am having is that my answer is turning out wrong, but only by a couple hundreds.

With the code I have now, I am using the example for Semi-Annually:

```
PV = 1000
Interest Rate = 3
Years Invested = 10
Compounded = Semi Annually
```

The answer I get is 1806.

The correct answer is 1346.86, supposedly.

The code I have is here:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String input1 = textInitialAmount.getText();
        String input2 = textAnnualInterest.getText();
        String input3 = textNumberOfYears.getText();
        String comp = textCompounded.getText();

        double invest = Double.parseDouble(input1);
        double interest = Double.parseDouble(input2);
        double numberofyear = Double.parseDouble(input3);

        if(comp.equals("Annually"))
        {
            double compPeriod = 1;
            double compNumberOfYear = numberofyear * compPeriod;
            double rate = (interest / 100) + 1;

            double valueFuture = invest * Math.pow(rate, compNumberOfYear);
            String output = String.format("%5.0f", valueFuture);

            futureValue.setText("The future value is " + output);
        }
        if (comp.equals("Semi-Annually"))
        {
            double compPeriod = 2;
            double compNumberOfYear = compPeriod * numberofyear;
            double percentRate = interest / 100;
            double rate = percentRate + 1;

            double valueFuture = invest * Math.pow(rate, compNumberOfYear);
            String output = String.format("%5.0f", valueFuture);

            futureValue.setText("The future value is " + output);
        }
        if(comp.equals("Monthly"))
        {
            double compPeriod = 12;
            double compNumberOfYear = compPeriod * numberofyear;
            double rate = 1 + (interest / 100);

            double valueFuture = invest * Math.pow(rate, compNumberOfYear);
            String output = String.format("%5.0f", valueFuture);

            futureValue.setText("The future value is " + output);
        }
        if(comp.equals("Bi-Weekly"))
        {

        }       
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help. Please comment if you need me to explain more.

Comment: Why do your annual and monthly calculations have the same `compPeriod` of `1`?  Shouldn't monthly be `12`?

Comment: please remove all the UI-related code and isolate the problem to the specific functions that aren't right.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application? Which calculation isn't behaving as you expect (which `futureValue`)? Also, what value do you expect (and what do you get)?

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry about that, I should change it. I was experimenting. Ill fix it now.

Comment: @Alnitak Removed all the other unrelated code. Now its just the functions that I am having issues with.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the correct answer is `1346.86`.  If you are compounding semi-annually by 3% for 10 years, that's `1.03^20`, which is `1.806111...`.

Comment: @azurefrog Is that correct then? Cause that is the amount that I am getting....I was using an online calculator so maybe it is calculating it wrong....Okay then. I have a different question, if thats okay. How do I round those numbers off to 2 decimals?

Comment: If the 3% is per year, then semi-annual interest would represent 1.5%.  1.015^20 is about 1.346855.

Comment: `1.03^10 = 1.34391...`, which is close to the `1346.86` you got.  Financial institutions do weird things to math.  I think @rgettman hit it on the head.  They are taking the 'anual' interest and dividing it by the rate of compounding, to get something close to, but not really, 3%. According to [this site](http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php) the formula you want to use is `A = P (1 + r/n) ^ nt`

Comment: There is an awful lot of duplicated code here.

Comment: I mean its all the same code, But say I do another example, like, 4000 for FV, 5% for interest, and 10 years, then compounded semi-annually. When I enter the code onto a calculator, I get around 2560.17, on my application I get 10613...

Comment: Check my answer. Your problem is not in your code; your problem is that you forgot to convert the interest rate to an *efective* rate per compounding period. I think you should take a look to a good book in Theory of interest, like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Interest-Stephen-Kellison/dp/0073382442/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1421969307&sr=1-1&keywords=kellison+theory+of+interest)

Comment: @azurefrog "Financial institutions do weird things to math"... hmm, it's just that you need to know how to convert annual interest rates (which are almost always nominal) to *efective* interest rates per compounding period

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not related to coding... it's related to the way you're dealing with interest rates!

- If you compound the interest Annually, you have 1 conversion period per year.
- If you compound the interest Biannually (or "Semiannually" as your question says), you have **2** periods per year, and you have to convert the interest rate to an efective Biannual interest rate *before* computing the interest.

The correct code would be something like this:

```
double compPeriod = 2;
double compNumberOfYear = compPeriod * numberOfYear;
double percentRate = (interest / compPeriod) / 100;
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                    You missed this!
double rate = percentRate + 1;
double valueFuture = invest * Math.pow(rate, compNumberOfYear);
```

Do it by hand:

- Interest rate: 3%
- Compound periods: 2
- Years: 10
- Periods: 2 * 10 = 20
- ***Efective*** interest rate: 3% / 2 = 1.5%
- Investment: 1000
- Future value: 1000 * (1 + 0.015)^20 = **1346.85500655**

---

**A little gift: *Cleaner and simpler code*** (Because I'm a nice guy ;) )

You're aufully duplicating your code! You can clean it up:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String input1 = textInitialAmount.getText();
        String input2 = textAnnualInterest.getText();
        String input3 = textNumberOfYears.getText();
        String comp = textCompounded.getText();

        double invest = Double.parseDouble(input1);
        double interest = Double.parseDouble(input2);
        double numberofyear = Double.parseDouble(input3);
        // You just need to declare variables once!
        double compPeriod; 
        switch(comp.toLowerCase()) {
            case "annually":
                compPeriod = 1;
                break;
            case "semiannually":
                compPeriod = 2;
                break;
            case "monthly":
                compPeriod = 12;
                break;
            case "bi-weekly":
                compPeriod = 26; // Assuming 52 weeks per year
                break;
            case "weekly":
                compPeriod = 52; // Assuming 52 weeks per year
                break;
            default:
                compPeriod = 1;
        }
        double compNumberOfYear = numberofyear * compPeriod;
        double valueFuture = invest * Math.pow(1 + (interest / compPeriod) / 100, compNumberOfYear);
        String output = String.format("%5.0f", valueFuture);
        futureValue.setText("The future value is " + output);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nathan happy to help. If you find this post useful, please up-vote it and/or accept it... and if you're studying financial maths or theory of interest, you need to get a good book on the topic